# Changing Razer keyboard's RGB settings on startup

Tags: scripts, keyboard, startup

I have a Razer RGB keyboard:Razer Black widow chroma and I want to set a default color on it for my Ubuntu on startup. The reason I need it is because I have Ubuntu on dual boot together with Windows and I use a different color scheme on my Windows.

I have downloaded the razergenie program together with the daemon and the drivers from the open-razer repository and I can change the colors manually. I wanted to know if there is some kind of a script I could automatically execute on startup to have the system change the colors for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found the answer to my problem.
According to Open Razer documentation https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer/wiki/Using-the-keyboard-driver ,

In order to change my keyboard's RGB settings I had to rewrite the appropriate files in `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/razerkbd/<DEVICE ID>/`
One has to write the command

`echo -n -e "\xFF\x00\xFF" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/razerkbd/<DEVICE ID>/matrix_effect_static`

Where you can replace `xFF\X00\xFF` by **any** hex code you wish.

Finally write a shell script with this command and have Ubuntu execute it on startup.

Comment: Can't write to `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/razerkbd/matrix_effect_static` not even with `sudo`. I get: "Permission denied". :(

Comment: This worked: x@x:/sys/bus/hid/drivers/razerkbd/0003:1532:0226.0011$ sudo echo -n -e "\xFF\x66\x00" > matrix_effect_static there was another subdirectory in my case. Thanks!